# Spring security redirect to static resources after authentication

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, graphics

Good morning,
I am writing an application using Spring security (latest version) and Spring MVC (latest version).

After securying everything was ok, the form and the controller, together with Spring security configuration worked well and the login was always successful.

Then I added a custom css and some images to display a better graphic, here it came the problem:
everytime I login I am first redirected to the login.css file rather than the homepage, although the login is successful I first see a blank page with the url of the css.

**Spring Security configuration**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            //configure security for pages
            .antMatchers(new String[]{"/login", "/accessDenied"}).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasAnyRole('admin', 'operatore')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            //creates login form
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/accessDenied")
            .usernameParameter("id_utente").passwordParameter("password")
            //catches exceptions http 403 response
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
    
    http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}
```

Static resources are under the path `/static/css` and `/static/images`.
I read this problem comes from the fact that Spring security redirects you to the last requested url after login, as to resolve the issue I tried using

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)
{
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
}
```

but it didn't work.

Are there any way to solve this problem?

**EDIT**

I already tried using

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            //configure security for pages
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(new String[]{"/login", "/accessDenied"}).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasAnyRole('admin', 'operatore')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            //creates login form
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/accessDenied")
            .usernameParameter("id_utente").passwordParameter("password")
            //catches exceptions http 403 response
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
    
    http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}
```

But I am anyhow redirected after a successufl login to a 404 page with url "http://localhost:8080/static/css/login.css". In the login page the static resources are corretcly served as the style is how I expect it to be.

**EDIT #2**

I Edited as Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana said, but it keeps redirecting to the css (showing the code inside this time) instead of the homepage.
The project structure is:

[image]

Resource handler is added this way:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
}
```

and updated configuration is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            //configure security for pages
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(new String[]{"/login", "/accessDenied"}).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasAnyRole('admin', 'operatore')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            //creates login form
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/accessDenied")
            .usernameParameter("id_utente").passwordParameter("password")
            //catches exceptions http 403 response
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
    
    http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}
```

Inside login page the css is linked this way:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/static/css/login.css" />">
```

With the new `antMatchers` the result is not a 404 but the code inside the css. By the way, the linked css is not served anymore as style is not displayed correctly if I use the new configuration and "/static/css/login.css" or "/css/login.css", none of the two link work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `static/css` and `static/images` are under the `static` directory, they will be served at `/css` and `/images` respectively.

You can permit all requests to those resources in your HTTP security configuration.

```java
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
    // ...
```

Comment: I already tried using this in the form of `.antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()`, resources are correctly served as the style is how I expect it to be, but after the login I am redirected again to a 404 page with the url "http://localhost:8080/static/css/login.css" and not to homepage as stated in `.defaultSuccessUrl("/home")`

Comment: localhost:8080/static/css/login.css is not found because the resource should be served on localhost:8080/css/login.css. In your HTML page, make sure you are referencing `/css/login.css` and not `/static/css/login.css`. Then the authorization rules should work.

Comment: Alternatively, if you always want to redirect to the same page after login, you can disable the request cache in the `configure` method `http.requestCache().disable()`

Comment: I edited the question to show the new situation after the changes.

Comment: I am sorry, I lately see the second comment about disabling the request cache, it actually worked as I am redirected to the homepage, but does it have any other impact on the performance or is only affecting that particular redirection?

Comment: By default, the request cache is only used to get the stored URL after the user is authenticated, so it will not impact the performance of your application (as long as you haven't configured the application to use `RequestCache` somewhere else)

Comment: I didn't do it, so i think it actually will not affect anything else, thanks a lot for the answers.